# Kalman filter android

Tags: android, kalman-filter

I tried to implement the code below which i got from code.google.com
I am getting error like org.ejml cannot be resolved, SimpleMatrix cannot be resolved and DenseMatrix64F cannot be resolved. What is the solution for this ?

you can get the code in this link

http://code.google.com/p/android-lucid-dreaming-app/source/browse/Lucid+Dreaming+App/src/com/luciddreamingapp/actigraph/filter/SimpleFilter.java?r=15

Answer (score 1):

Your project is missing external jars where these classes are defined. Make sure to include all the libraries under `lib` folder to your classpath (right click on the jars within eclipse and select `Build Path -> Add to Build Path`.

You will need the following jars `EJML-nogui.jar`, `commons-math_trimmed2.jar` and `gson-1.7.1.jar`